# Does anyone know why the "dishonest act" question get bumped?

Tags: discussion

I'm calling this a bug, but there might be a reasonable explaination.  The [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/389/68) doesn't seem to be anything special but fairly regularly it seems to be bumped to the top of the queue by the Community user.  There never seem to be any new edits or other reason for this question to come back in view.  Anyone know why this happens?

---

Caleb [answered](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/287/68) why this happens.  So I guess we ought to figure out how to clean up the question so that it can be answered.  Or [answer it](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/1258/68).  Or vote up one of the answers.  Or close it.

I've done two of the four, now.  Let's see is anyone will do one of the other two...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug. Questions with no upvoted answers periodically get bumped on a rotating schedule. Just having an answer doesn't qualify a question as all tidied up, it needs at least one answer to be in the green on the vote count.

I suspect there are very few questions around here with no upvoted answers, which would explain why you've seen that one several times. I most commonly see this on meta sites where people will post something that really doesn't need answering, and unless somebody actually posts an answer that gets upvoted it will keep getting bumped the meta home page.